# Java application startup time with newrelic agent

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I'm running a java application on Heroku with the newrelic agent. I see from the logs that it can take > 8 seconds to start the newrelic agent - sometimes more. From the example below it looks like it takes 2 seconds to load instrumentation, and perhaps 5 seconds to connect to the new relic server.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Sometimes it seems like things are working slower than usual and I hit the 90s bootup heroku limit (`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch`).

Most of the instrumentation shown below is not required.

Thanks.

```
05:56:21 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent: Loading configuration file "/app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
05:56:21 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent v3.37.0 is initializing...
05:56:22 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic.agent.deps.org.reflections.Reflections WARN: given scan urls are empty. set urls in the configuration
... 46 others
05:56:22 +0000 [4 8] com.newrelic INFO: Instrumentation com.newrelic.instrumentation.akka-2.2 is enabled. Loading.
05:56:23 +0000 [4 11] com.newrelic INFO: Instrumentation com.newrelic.instrumentation.async-http-client-2.0.0 is enabled. Loading.
... 128 others
05:56:23 +0000 [4 6] com.newrelic INFO: Instrumentation com.newrelic.instrumentation.solr-1.4.0 is enabled. Loading.
05:56:27 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic.agent.RPMServiceManagerImpl INFO: Configured to connect to New Relic at collector.newrelic.com:443
05:56:27 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: Setting audit_mode to false
05:56:27 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: Setting protocol to "https"
05:56:28 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic.agent.config.ConfigServiceImpl INFO: Configuration file is /app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml
05:56:28 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent v3.37.0 has started
05:56:28 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: Agent class loader: com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent$JVMAgentClassLoader@533ddba
05:56:28 +0000 [4 1] com.newrelic INFO: Premain startup complete in 7,981ms
```

Answer (score 0):

How about change this config value?

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/configuration/java-agent-configuration-config-file

sync_startup
Type    Boolean Default false
Enable the agent to connect the New Relic collector immediately upon app startup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out

Comment: Looks like `sync_startup: false` is the default anyway. Makes no difference explicitly setting it.

Comment: Using `sync_startup: true` seems to make a difference. Instrumentation still takes 10s but it looks like connecting to the server might be happening after my app starts booting (looks to be ASYNC by the logs). Would be good if instrumentation could be sped up.

Comment: I'm still not having much luck. I think I'm just going to have to remove newrelic - it's just adding too much to the startup time.